# How to place images within a listview widget?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Hey so I have tried a few tutorials but so far no luck figuring out my problem. So I am trying to place some images on a listview widget. However, I am only using images as banners and I am pretty much trying to make a scrollable list of pictures promoting "specials". So when I try to make an array I was encouraged to use type int in my array. And if so how do I incorporate these integer values as the images in my images resource folder? So far I'm stuck so heres some code so far:

```
package com.demoapp.oscar.redmoon;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class specials extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.specials);

    String[] specialImages;
    ListView specialList;

    Integer[] images = {R.drawable.freeDrink, R.drawable.HappyHour,
            R.drawable.munchieMondays,R.drawable.whackyWed};

    ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
            ,images);

    specialList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.specials_list);

    specialList.setAdapter(theAdapter);
}
```

}

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You have to implement custom list view this link will help you to understand the flow. http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: Its a bit complicated to what I am used to but I haven't checked custom list view I'll check'em out. Thanks!